# ASP.NET MVC 5 Dynamic Azure AD connectivity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory

I am currently building a SaaS - application with ASP.NET MVC 5 as the core platform. One of the requirements is to allow tenants to login with their Azure AD Accounts.

Here is the background story:

*It's a multi tenant application where each customer/tenant can have multiple users. Tenants share the same instance of the application, so they will ultimately all navigate to the same URL (myapplication.com). We allow users to login with their organizational accounts (Azure AD, Office 365). Since all tenants go to the same URL, we cannot determine upfront which client ID/secret to use as this will only work for just one client. By using subdomains, we can identify the client (e.g. client1.ourapplication.com), so we can retrieve the Azure AD data from the database.The next step would be to use pass this data to the OpenID Authentication Options for each request that comes in, instead of 'hard coding' it in compile time during the startup of the application.*

The issue that I'm currently facing is how I can get rid of the hard coded ClientId and AppKeys in the Web.Config (or database, as is in this case) and dynamically change these values according to the user that is logging in. In other words, I need to create the Azure AD login provider on the fly for every login request.

In the full code sample below, I somehow need to be able to set this line app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(...) during runtime and not during the startup of the application with the updated clientID and appKey of the tenant in question.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{    
  string clientId = string.Empty;
  string appKey = string.Empty;

  ConfigurationWorker worker = new ConfigurationWorker(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>());
  IEnumerable<Config> azureAdConfiguration = worker.GetConfiguration("AzureId", "AzurePassword").Result;

  if (azureAdConfiguration != null && azureAdConfiguration.Count() == 2)
  {
   clientId = azureAdConfiguration.First(x => x.Key == "AzureId").Value;
   appKey = azureAdConfiguration.First(x => x.Key == "AzurePassword").Value;
  }

  string graphResourceID = "https://graph.windows.net";
  string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";

  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(this.GetAzureADLoginProvider(clientId, appKey, Authority, graphResourceID));

 }

private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions GetAzureADLoginProvider(string clientId, string appKey, string Authority, string graphResourceID)
{
        return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    var code = context.Code;

                    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                    string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                    string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenantID));
                    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                        code,
                        new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)),
                        credential,
                        graphResourceID);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                    // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                    // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                    string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                    context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                // we use this notification for injecting our custom logic
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    // Once user has logged in, create and replace existing claims identity
                    ClaimsIdentity newClaimsIdentity = ClaimsHelper.Create(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity, (x) => Singleton.Instance().Logger.LogInformation(x));

                    // Ultimately add tenant ID from azure to claims identity
                    Claim tenantIdClaim = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid");
                    newClaimsIdentity.AddClaim(tenantIdClaim);

                    // Set context's user to the new claim identity
                    context.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newClaimsIdentity, context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                MessageReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
  }
```

This is the AccountController's action that will be executed if the user selects to login with Azure AD:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public void SignInAzure()
{
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            this.AuthenticationManager.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("AzureADCallback", new { returnUrl = "~/" }) },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
                );
        }
}
```

Can I somehow set the clientID and AppKey in this controller? Because at this point I'm able to determine the tenant (using the subdomain), which allows me to query the correct values (in the database).

Something like this pseudocode would be awesome to have:

```
this.AuthenticationManager.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.ClientID= NEWID;
this.AuthenticationManager.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.AppKey= NEWAPPKEY;
```

Or equally as well create the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions object on the fly per request.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Update:

As a workaround for this issue, I currently use this approach, as suggested by this [solution](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/OnboardingController.cs):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignInAzure()
    {
        // Resolve tenant
        string currentTenant = this.HttpContext.Request?.RequestContext?.RouteData?.Values["tenant"]?.ToString();

        IEnumerable<Config> configKeys = await this.ConfigurationWorker.GetConfiguration(currentTenant, ConfigurationKeys.AzureId, ConfigurationKeys.AzurePassword);

        string clientId = string.Empty;
        string appKey = string.Empty;
        if (configKeys != null && configKeys.Count() == 2)
        {
            clientId = configKeys.First(x => x.Key == ConfigurationKeys.AzureId).Value;
            appKey = configKeys.First(x => x.Key == ConfigurationKeys.AzurePassword).Value;
        }

        string stateMarker = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string returnUrl = this.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString() + "/Account/AzureADCallback";
        string authorizationRequest = String.Format(
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&resource={1}&redirect_uri={2}&state={3}",
             Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId),
             Uri.EscapeDataString("https://graph.windows.net"),
             Uri.EscapeDataString(returnUrl),
             Uri.EscapeDataString(stateMarker)
             );
        authorizationRequest += String.Format("&prompt={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString("admin_consent"));
        return new RedirectResult(authorizationRequest);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AzureADCallback(string code, string error, string error_description, string resource, string state)
    {
        // Resolve tenant
        string currentTenant = this.HttpContext.Request?.RequestContext?.RouteData?.Values["tenant"]?.ToString();
        IEnumerable<Config> configKeys = await this.ConfigurationWorker.GetConfiguration(ConfigurationKeys.AzureId, ConfigurationKeys.AzurePassword);

        string clientId = string.Empty;
        string appKey = string.Empty;
        if (configKeys != null && configKeys.Count() == 2)
        {
            clientId = configKeys.First(x => x.Key == ConfigurationKeys.AzureId).Value;
            appKey = configKeys.First(x => x.Key == ConfigurationKeys.AzurePassword).Value;
        }

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/");
        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential);

        var user = this.UserManager.FindByEmail(result.UserInfo.DisplayableId);
        await this.SignInAsync(user, false);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

In a nutshell, the tenant is resolved from the URL (subdomains) after which the database is called to get the Azure ID and Secret. This is used to generate the URL for the user to login. After the user has logged in to Azure AD, an AuthenticationResult is generated and the user is signed in to the application.

Comment: no of Azure AD tenant is fixed or it is too being added dynamically as and when application grow?

Comment: The number of tenants is unknown, it will grow and shrink as customers will come and go.

Comment: Hi Hbulens. This is a very interesting question. To help us help you, can you explain your scenario a bit more? What do you hope to accomplish by changing the App ID/Client Secret on the fly? Will you be creating new application objects per user, or do you have like 3 apps set up currently and want to switch between them? Thanks!

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi See updated question. I should point out that we temporarily have abandoned the OpenID approach and chosen the approach that is suggested in the GitHub solution 'active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect'. It works perfectly but it kind of ignores the whole authorization configuration in ASP.NET MVC.